# how to fix net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: .net, http2

I have a website that run on dotnet

this morning out of nowhere there is one page where all links are not working,
all js, css have the same error in console
**net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

it does that on all browsers

Comment: any chance a load-balancer / reverse-proxy is misconfigured?